# How to add items from ArrayList<Model> to ArrayList<String> in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I've been searching all over the internet and SO for hours. I've seen numerous examples/answers for how to add items from ArrayList to another ArrayList but can't seem to find anything that explains how to add items from an ArrayList to ArrayList.

I have a wizard that saves selections to two different ArrayList's. The first screen saves the selected items to an ArrayList, another screen saves selected items to an ArrayList then the last screen displays the total items selected from the ArrayList.

I've tried `stringArrayList.add(modelArrayList)` but that gives the error that String cannot be applied to model.

**EDIT: Added classes**

To clarify and make things more clear as to what I'm working with.
I'm implementing a "wizard" using [WizarDroid Library](https://github.com/Nimrodda/WizarDroid) and the page I'm trying to merge two different ArrayList's on is based off of this multi choice tutorial [here](http://adanware.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-multiple-selection-listview.html).

Model Class:

```
    public class NSBaseModel {
    private String baseName;

    public NSBaseModel(String name)
    {
        baseName = name;

    }

    public String getBaseName() {
        return baseName;
    }

}
```

Wizard page:

```
    public class FormStepBase extends WizardStep {

    ArrayList<NSBaseModel> baseNames;
    ArrayList<NSBaseModel> selectedItems = new ArrayList<NSBaseModel>();
    NSBaseAdapter myAdapter;
    ListView myListView;

    //You must have an empty constructor for every step
    public FormStepBase() {
    }

    //Set your layout here
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        List<String> Lines = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.NAL_smoothie_base));

        baseNames = new ArrayList<NSBaseModel>();
        baseNames.add...//Long list of items here

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.step_base, container, false);

        myListView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.nsBaseListView);
        myAdapter = new NSBaseAdapter(v.getContext(), R.layout.row_base_layout, baseNames);
        myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        myListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);


        return v;



    }

    /**
     * Called whenever the wizard proceeds to the next step or goes back to the previous step
     */

    @Override
    public void onExit(int exitCode) {
        switch (exitCode) {
            case WizardStep.EXIT_NEXT:
                //saveBaseIngredients();


                final SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = myListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
                int checkedItemsCount = checkedItems.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < checkedItemsCount; ++i) {
                    // Item position in adapter
                    int position = checkedItems.keyAt(i);
                    // Add team if item is checked == TRUE!
                    if(checkedItems.valueAt(i))
                        selectedItems.add(myAdapter.getItem(position));
                    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
                        selectedItems.get(i);
                        System.out.print("option list size");
                        System.out.print(selectedItems.size());

                        //reference to static ArrayList<String> here
                        CreateList.nsList.add(selectedItems);

                    }
                }
                if(selectedItems.size() < 2)
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Need to select two or more items.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                {
                    // Just logging the output.
                    for(NSBaseModel t : selectedItems)
                        Log.d("SELECTED TEAMS: ", t.getBaseName());
                        //Thought I could get the strings from here since they show in the logcat

                }

                break;
            case WizardStep.EXIT_PREVIOUS:
                //Do nothing...
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

In my CreateList class I have `public static ArrayList<String> nsList = new ArrayList<String>();`

**EDIT**

Solved my issue thanks to @Polichronis Charitidis. His answer ended up being the correct solution. The reason it wasn't working for me is because I had declared `int i` in both my for loops thus confusing the system and result. I had to change the `int i` variable in my second for loop to a different letter and now it works. This is how my second "for" loop looks now.

```
for (int j = 0; j < selectedItems.size(); j++) {
                    selectedItems.get(i);
                    System.out.print("option list size");
                    System.out.print(selectedItems.size());
                    CreateList.nsList.add(selectedItems.get(j).getBaseName());

                }
```

Comment: Where is `stringArrayList` and `modelArrayList` declaration, And what is inside them ?

Comment: You can't, you can add only type String to List<String> and you can add only type Model to List<Model>

Comment: show your `Model class`

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change this line

```
stringArrayList.add(modelArrayList);
```

to this:

```
stringArrayList.add(modelArrayList.get(i).getBaseName());
```

so that you can add the String name from the Model ArrayList to the String ArrayList.

Comment: With this I can run my app and go through the wizard but on the last page where its supposed to show a list of all the items that were selected it shows a list of NSBaseModel@42042840 and so on with each item having a different number after NSBaseModel@ when its supposed to show the string

Comment: yes because you are still using the NSBaseModel ArrayList and not the String one that you created. Change it and try again.

Comment: Ok. I think I misunderstood you. Could you clarify or elaborate a little more on what you mean please? I'm not a total noob but I'm not advanced either. :)

Comment: The class you see above isn't where I added the line you stated here. I changed stringArrayList.add(modelArrayList); to what you suggested and thats where I'm getting the weird result

Comment: you have to find where exactly your code passes the data from ArrayList to the output adapter. I pretty sure that you use the wrong ArrayList. You need to replace it with the String ArrayList you have created.

Comment: Please see my last edit. Thank you for your answer. I was getting that strange result because I had `int i` in both for loops. It works perfectly now. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad that i could help.

Comment: @xro7 could you please see this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68050680/how-to-display-data-from-one-activitys-recyclerview-to-another-activitys-recyc

Answer (score 0):

why not is to loop over it and convert each item into a new Arraylist of strings yourself:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object yourmodelArralistObject: list) {
strings.add(yourmodelArralistObject!= null ? 
yourmodelArralistObject.toString() : null); 
}
```

Note that you should be declaring against the interface (java.util.List in this case), not the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, in the above code (which I am not quoting here, because it is plain wrong) you are iterating though the array list and at every single iteration you are adding the whole array list to another one. That is just wrong and won't work.

1. First make sure you initialize the stringArrayList before (you are not showing that in the above snippet, and I expect you doing so, but just to be sure...
2. Use for loops as they should be used:

   ArrayList stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i = 0; i < modelArrayList.size(); i++) {
       stringArrayList.add(modelArrayList.get(i);
   }
3. As `String` is an `Object` and not a primitive, you are adding references to the `ArrayList` and therefore even if you add it from one `ArrayList` to another one, it will be the same object, and not two different `Objects`. If you modify it in one of them, it will change in the other too. Implement a way to properly copy it.

Hope that helps!